# Correct tense/time? "She would get you fired before you had sent your complaint"

Tags: tense, past-perfect, conditional-constructions

I am not sure about using past perfect in sentences like this. To be honest, I don't even know what is that - mixed condition, unreal time?

> "She would get you fired before you had sent your complaint"

I want to emphasize that he would not even finish the sending the complaint, that is why I use past perfect in this context.

Comment: Probably more natural as: *She'd have you fired before you could send your complaint.*

Comment: Yes but that would mean "before you start complaining". But imagine he is already calling someone, complaining about her..but before he finished, she got him fired.

Comment: Ok, there is a fine line between "actually hitting *send*" on your complaint and starting it, and the difference is in whether you say, "send **a** complaint" - meaning you haven't started one yet, or "send **your** complaint" which might mean you have one started, but could also mean you just have one formulated in your head. But that aside you could say, "...before you could **finish** your complaint" if you preferred.

Comment: Thanks, still not get it completely. So the present perfect I used in the example would not work? It would mean basically same, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think your example is phrased fine.

Comment: I agree with Peter; I don't see anything wrong with your version. I get what Jim is saying as well, but I understand that you want the in-progress kind of feel. There's a slight contrast between your question and your comment though; "sent your complaint" implies filing a written complaint. "Calling someone and complaining" is different; that process obviously takes more time. If that's your intent I'd go with something like "...before you had finished complaining [about her actions]."

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you "want to emphasize that he would not even finish the sending the complaint" it seems to me that any indicative, perfect or otherwise, would be misleading. I suggest you use an irrealis version of *can* or *be able*:

> She would get you fired before you *could* send your complaint.
>   She would get you fired before you *would be able to* send your complaint.